# How can I find out if someone from the user's contacts is already using my app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase

I'm trying to build an system similar to whatsapp where I first display users who are already members on my app followed by an invite section to invite other users from their contacts.

My current solution is checking each phone number from the user's contact list if they are a member, but obviously this is quite expensive and takes forever if a user has thousands of contacts. What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: If you have a list of items and you want to check something for each item, there is no way other than traversing the whole list.

Comment: How do apps like clubhouse and whatsapp handle the same features? I would assume you have to check each phone number on your contact list there as well.

Comment: I have code in my app that iterates through the contacts and the phone numbers in each contact, I've tested it with thousands and thousands and have no problems, and while its not instant it is certainly not too long that it creates issues.
Firstly maybe you have some inefficiency in what you are doing.
Secondly, are you running your code in the main thread? If so you'll lock up the ui, move it to a background thread.